# Tracking how many times a user has ranked above X place in a "Weekly High Score" database

Tags: php, mysql, database

My application has a `VIEW` of another table that displays a list of all recorded high scores for the last calendar week.  Each week, I'd like to increment a value in the rows of every user who is in the top X of this list to indicate that they've been in said top X however many weeks in the past. Since I'm only using a date filter and there's no sort of server side "event" firing off each week, I'm not sure of the most efficient way to register this information on a weekly basis.

One way I can think of doing so is to simply run some sort of "check" every time a user logs on, and the first user to log on each calendar week shoulders the burden of telling the server to increment the top X users of last week.  While this seems a bit hokey to me, I will gladly do it with enough Internet Approval.

The main languages I'm working with are MySQL and PHP, in case it's of relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an update script that 1) Checks when it run last, and if that was this week, then abort. 2) Update the last-run timestamp. 3) Process the previous week. Now you can schedule this script with your operating system (either by running it with php, or by using e.g. wget to "download" the page). E.g. on linux you'd normally use cron, and task scheduler on windows. This is much better than using the first user because that can lead to race-conditions where it is hard to ensure that the processing cannot be run twice (in parallel).

Comment: Wow, never occurred to me to just automate the execution of a script at the OS level.  Thanks a lot for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider running a cron job. You can run a check each time a user logs in but this really isn't ideal, especially if your system is going to scale up.